# Display pressed shortcuts as an overlay on the screen

Tags: video, keyboard, screen-capture

On this great Ruby on Rails [screencast](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts), every time a shortcut combination is pressed it shows up on top of the screen, and it shows up so often that I find it hard to believe it was placed by hand when editing the movie.
Is there any application that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which specific screencast you're speaking of, but they may be using [Keycastr](http://stephendeken.net/software/keycastr/).

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry, it wasn't a Textmate screencast, it was the "Ruby on Rails 15 Minute Blog" screencast. 
It's this program, no doubt! Thanks a lot, I had searched this before to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness: [Boinx Software's Mouseposé](http://www.boinx.com/mousepose/) does this (and a lot more) as well ($17).